# Incorrect syntax when importing CSV File to MySQL (Editor: PopSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, sql-insert, load-data-infile

I have a Mock Dataset as a CSV file. I have been trying to import to a table in my database.
This is my code:

```
"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\MOCK_DATA (1).csv' 
INTO TABLE test_data (LINE_ID, DATE_ID, total_sales, check_avg, total_checks) 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';"
```

This is the code I have been using. I keep getting the following syntax error and I cannot pinpoint where I screwed up.

"ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','' at line 1."

Thank you very much in advance.
PS. What are some popular MySQL editors. Not much of a fan of PopSQL so far

Comment: Mysql Workbench and phpmyadmin(needs php and a webserver, but there are only marginal differences

Answer (score 0):

You can not define columns
read more in the [maula](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)
so use

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\MOCK_DATA (1).csv' 
INTO TABLE test_data  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Answer (score 0):

The column list specification goes at the very end of the statement (before the optional `SET` clause), so you have to put it *after* the `FIELDS` clause:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\MOCK_DATA (1).csv' 
INTO TABLE test_data 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(line_id, date_id, total_sales, check_avg, total_checks);
```